# How to convert List<String> to Map<String, Int> in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, collections, hashmap

For example I have a list of strings like:

val list = listOf("a", "b", "a", "b" "a" "c")
and I need to convert it to a Map, where the strings are the keys and values are count of repetitions. So i have to got Map like [a = 3] [b = 2] [c = 1]

Answer (score 2):

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "c")

val result = list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()

// result is Map<String, Int> looking like this: {a=3, b=2, c=1}
```

Edit: for counts bigger than 1 add a filter condition to the map

```
val result = list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().filter { it.value > 1 }

// result is now: {a=3, b=2}
```

Comment: thank you, and what if I need only pairs, where values > 1